# Calcular la posición del thumb de un slider en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Quiero colocar el valor seleccionado de un `Slider` encima de su `thumb`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He introducido el siguiente código:

```
miSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {

        información.textProperty().setValue(
                String.valueOf((int) miSlider.getValue()));

        // posiciono la información
        información.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0, 
               (miSlider.getValue() - miSlider.getMax()) * miSlider.getWidth() / 
               (miSlider.getMax()-miSlider.getMin()) + miSlider.getWidth() ));                        
    }
});
```

El `Label` información no se sitúa justo encima del `thumb`. ¿Cómo obtengo la posición del `thumb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa `getBoundsInParent()` y `lookUp()`:

```
Bounds dimensiones = slider.lookup(".thumb").getBoundsInParent();
```

Necesitarás aplicar `CSS` al `Slider` con `applyCss()` antes de `lookUp` para que se muestre la posición correctamente.

Esta respuesta es una traducción de la respuesta que tienes en este enlace junto a un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131485/coordinates-of-slider-thumb-in-javafx